# Find a bijection function from $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to find bijection
$$
f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Z}
$$
Such a function exists, because the two sets have the same cardinality, but I can't find an explicit one, any ideas?

Comment: How do you know the sets have the same cardinality? You should be able to use that to find an explicit bijection.

Comment: If you can find a bijection between $[0, 1)$ and $(0, 1)$ then you are done since you can glue these pieces together to form $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: You are right, but the exercise is to prove that the sets have the same cardinality, not using the Cantor–Bernstein theorem, but to find an explicit function.

Comment: Cantor-Bernstein *gives* an explicit function!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Fix $a_n$ as a sequence of irrational numbers, and write $\mathbb Z=\{z_n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$. Define a function which sends $a_n$ to $a_{2n}$; $z_n$ to $a_{2n+1}$; and $x$ to itself otherwise.

Comment: Thanks Asaf! But to fix $a_{n}$, irrational numbers should be countable. How do I define the sequence properly?

Comment: @Denis: The irrational numbers are not countable, of course. But does that mean that there is no countable sequence of irrational numbers?? $k+\pi$ for $k\in\mathbb N$, for example? Square roots of square-free integers? And so on and so forth...

Comment: OK, you mean not to map all the irrational numbers as sequence, but to choose one specific irrational sequence like $k+\pi$ ?

Comment: @Denis: Hence the term "Fix $a_n$ as a sequence **of** irrational numbers", and not "Fix $a_n$ as a sequence **of the** irrational numbers".

Comment: I see! Thanks, very elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. Take $f:(0,1)\to(0,1]$ to be the inclusion map and define $g:(0,1]\to(0,1)$ by $g(x)=x/2$. These are injections.
2. Find a proof of the Cantor-Bernstein theorem which doesn't use the axiom of choice.
3. Follow the proof using $f$ and $g$ to produce a bijection $h:(0,1)\to(0,1]$.
4. Using translations of $h$ you get a bijection $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Z\to\Bbb R$.

Comment: Yes, I didn't think to use the algorithm of the proof to find the explicit function. Thanks!